# Is it safe to create bean that contains username and password?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a configuration file for 3rd party services. I have my configuration properties as this.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bezon.authentication")
class AuthenticationProperties {
   private String username;
   private String password;
}
```

I'm not familiar with Spring boot but as far as I understand this bean will be accessible by every components. So I'm not sure if it's safe to do that? Is it possible to limit the scope of this bean.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely unsafe like that but if you add the following to application properties you can provide them both as environment variables (or secrets in something like kubernetes)

```
bezon.authentication.username=${USERNAME_ENV_VAR}
bezon.authentication.password=${PASSWORD_ENV_VAR}
```

and then set these vars in the environment (or create secrets)